# Determine list of permissions used by an installed application in Android

Tags: android, permissions

I have to determine list of permission used each by the installed application on my device.

I have got the list of applications installed and there package name using the following code:

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<ResolveInfo> list = m.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

  for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {   
   Log.d("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
     .loadLabel(pm).toString());
   Log.d("packegename",rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName.
           toString());
     }
```

How do I get permission used by each application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [freetaskmanager](http://code.google.com/p/freetaskmanager/)

```
        // Loop through all installed packaged to get a list of used permissions and PackageInfos
    for (PackageInfo pi : appList) {            
        // Do not add System Packages
        if ((pi.requestedPermissions == null || pi.packageName.equals("android")) || 
                (pi.applicationInfo != null && (pi.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0)) 
            continue;


        for (String permission : pi.requestedPermissions) {
            Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            try {
                PermissionInfo pinfo = mPm.getPermissionInfo(permission, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                CharSequence label = pinfo.loadLabel(mPm);
                CharSequence desc = pinfo.loadDescription(mPm);
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring unknown permission " + permission);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

So i coded it.i needed not just the permissions but also the recievers and services.pls see the following code,hope its useful for others.

```
PackageManager p = this.getPackageManager();
  final List <PackageInfo> appinstall=p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS|PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS|
      PackageManager.GET_SERVICES|PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);

  for(PackageInfo pInfo:appinstall){
      //PermissionInfo[] permission=pInfo.permissions;
       String[] reqPermission=pInfo.requestedPermissions;
       ServiceInfo[] services=pInfo.services;
       ProviderInfo[] providers=pInfo.providers;

  int versionCode=pInfo.versionCode;
  Log.d("versionCode-package ",Integer.toString(versionCode));
  Log.d("Installed Applications", pInfo.applicationInfo
            .loadLabel(pm).toString());
  Log.d("packegename",pInfo.packageName.
           toString());
  if(reqPermission!=null)
    for(int i=0;i<reqPermission.length;i++)
       Log.d("permission list",reqPermission[i]);
```

}

NOTICE-setting flags is important otherwise it causes problem n u cnt get services ,provider
NOTE- NULL CHECK IS IMP OR IT GIVES NPE

also the previous code i wrote ws using activityInfo this one uses packageInfo .it better now i guess :)
happy coding ppl :)

Answer (score 2):

Here how to retrieve the list of the apps installed on an Android device, and the permissions used by every app.

```
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";  
...

final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for ( ApplicationInfo app : installedApps ) {
    //Details:
    Log.d(TAG, "Package: " + app.packageName);
    Log.d(TAG, "UID: " + app.uid);
    Log.d(TAG, "Directory: " + app.sourceDir);

    //Permissions:
    StringBuffer permissions = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(app.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
        if ( requestedPermissions != null ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
                permissions.append(requestedPermissions[i] + "\n");
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Permissions: " + permissions);
        }
    }
    catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing I found, though I've not tested it out.

Let me know if it works for any one:

```
pm.getPackageInfo(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, packageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
```