# Check if device is locked by third party App

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want to check programatically if my device is locked by a third party Lockscreen...With the normal Lockscreen by android you can do that by

```
KeyguardManager kgMgr = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
boolean locked = kgMgr.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
```

But what if a third party Lockscreen is installed?! Is there any way to check if the device is locked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the foreground app and check for its permissions using the `PackageManager` class.
To get the foreground application you can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service)  link.

Once you get the foreground app, you can fetch the permissions of that app. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461504/determine-list-of-permissions-used-by-an-installed-application-in-android)  link for this functionality.

Later, You can check whether its a system app or not by going through `getApplicationInfo` and later & with `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM`. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784505/how-do-i-check-if-an-app-is-a-non-system-app-in-android)  link on how to do that.

Comment: But what if there is a different Application in the foreground which is not a LockScreen but also needs the "android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"?! Than i will get wrong informations...

Answer (score 0):

I think that all custom lockscreens use the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />` permission. So your method should be correct in most of standard cases.

Comment: so i could get a list of all running processes and take the one with the priority that indicates that the app is in foreground. Is there a way to look into the Manifest of that app?!